Undefined reference to `id_to_sdl_format' when building pipewire exapmle
I'm trying to compile the example https://docs.pipewire.org/video-play_8c-example.html
After replacing #include "sdl.h" from line 30 with #include <SDL2/SDL.h>, I compile with gcc main.c -o custmain -lm $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libpipewire-0.3) -lSDL2main -lSDL2
This results in several compiler warnings and linker errors:
main.c:143:50: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘id_to_sdl_format’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main.c:404:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sdl_build_formats’; did you mean ‘build_format’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
main.c:(.text+0x5fe8): undefined reference to id_to_sdl_format'
main.c:(.text+0x706e): undefined reference to sdl_build_formats'`

I dont know of a flag -lm in gcc.

this is libm library @Raildex

if you look at the sdl example, id_to_sdl_format is static. so i guess you are supposed to either just copy&paste it or implement it yourself:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/blob/0.3.45/src/examples/sdl.h#L141

Apparently SDL changed the API. Did you check the expected version against your installed version?

I just took the https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/blob/0.3.45/src/examples/sdl.h file for myself and everything works
